# Add CustomAttributes field while calling the SageMaker Endpoint in LangChain

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, langchain, large-language-model

I am trying to use LangChain based on LLM hosted on a SageMaker endpoint.
In this [link](https://python.langchain.com/docs/integrations/llms/sagemaker) you can see the suggested code by LangChain documentation:

```
llm=SagemakerEndpoint(
        endpoint_name="endpoint-name",
        region_name="us-west-2",
        model_kwargs={"temperature": 1e-10},
        content_handler=content_handler,
    ),
```

But my endpoint requires passing the `CustomAttributes="accept_eula=true"` parameter. How can I do that?

For reference, I know following code works (which does not use LangChain)

```
client = boto3.client("sagemaker-runtime")
response = client.invoke_endpoint(
    EndpointName=endpoint_name,
    ContentType="application/json",
    Body=json.dumps(payload),
    CustomAttributes="accept_eula=true",
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe adding following argument solves the issue:

```
endpoint_kwargs={"CustomAttributes": 'accept_eula=true'},



llm=SagemakerEndpoint(
        endpoint_name="endpoint-name",
        region_name="us-west-2",
        model_kwargs={"temperature": 1e-10},
        content_handler=content_handler,
        endpoint_kwargs={"CustomAttributes": 'accept_eula=true'},

    ),
```